# Proving that $\forall x\exists y(x = y)$

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

How to prove in a formal system (like HFOL) the following formula $\forall x\exists y(x = y)$?

Obviously, we would like to use the axiom $x = x$ and then use a rule for introducing $\exists$, but how do we get $x = y$?

Comment: Please articulate what you mean by HFOL.  You don't mention the domains of $x, y$.  This is crucial, because if $x \in \mathbb R$, and  $y\in \mathbb N$, then the statement is not true.  But if $x, y$ are both in the same domain, then yes, $\forall x\exists y(x=y)$.

Comment: It is a basic proof system for first-order logic with equality.

Comment: From $\forall x(x=x)$ use universal instantiation $a=a$. Then existential generalization $\exists y(a=y)$. Then universal generalization $\forall x\exists y(x=y)$.

Comment: @flan but by the existential generalization, shouldn't we replace all the occurrences of $a$ with $y$?

Comment: See my answer posted just now at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033513/deduction-of-forall-y-exists-x-x-y

Comment: @user91015 Nope. You do not *need* to replace *all* occurrences of $a$.  Should $a=a$, there will exist some $y$ where $a=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible formal proof in a Fitch-style natural deduction system:

\begin{align*}
& 1. ~ a = a \mathrm{~(a.k.a.~}(a = y) [ y / a ] \mathrm{)} & \qquad & {=}I \\
& 2. ~ \exists y, a = y \mathrm{~(a.k.a.~}(\exists y, x = y) [ x / a ] \mathrm{)} & \qquad & {\exists}I, 1 \\
& 3. ~ \forall x, \exists y, x = y & \qquad & {\forall}I, 2
\end{align*}

Comment: Line (1.)  $I$ what??

Comment: I'm using ${=}I$ to stand for "equality introduction", a.k.a. the reflexivity axiom/rule of first order logic.

Comment: @amWhy OK, I should have suspected that would be the case.  Should I delete the answer, or just wait for this question to be closed as a duplicate?